# CentOS - Cant find sendmail config file

Tags: centos6, sendmail

I am running CentOS, but can't find the sendmail configuration file.

According to these instructions, [Common Sendmail Configuration Changes](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s3-email-mta-sendmail-changes.html), the config file should be in `/etc/mail/sendfile.cf`.

I don't have a mail folder in `/etc`.

I did a `whereis sendmail` and found it in `/usr/sbin/sendmail`. A search in `/usr/sbin/` could not locate the `sedmail.cf` nor could it find the `sendmail.mc` file.

How do I create a config file?

BTW, sendmail works, as I can send an email via the PHP function `mail()`.

Comment: You probably don't have sendmail installed but have postfix instead.  You can verify this by running `rpm -qfi /usr/sbin/sendmail`.

Comment: centos 6 runs postfix by default

Comment: Summary     : Postfix Mail Transport Agent    I have postfix installed!!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably don't have sendmail installed but have postfix instead. You can verify this by running
`rpm -qfi /usr/sbin/sendmail`.

As c4f4t0r commented, postfix is the default mailer in CentOS 6.  Sendmail is available but not installed by default.